# Why is expectation undefined?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, expected-value

My textbook says

> Consider a random variable $X$ that takes the values $2^k$ and $-2^k$ with probability $2^{-k}$, for $k = 2,3, \ldots$ . The expectation is undefined, even though the PMF is symmetric around zero and one might be tempted to say that $E[X]$ is zero.

My question: why is the expectation undefined?

My thoughts: pmf is as below, which has a center of mass at zero. So expectation should be zero.

Calculation of $E[X]:$ $$E[X]=\left(2^2\cdot \frac{1}{2^2}+2^3\cdot \frac{1}{2^3}+\cdots\right)-\left(2^2\cdot \frac{1}{2^2}+2^3\cdot \frac{1}{2^3}+\cdots\right)$$ $=0$
if we add the first term of the figure within the left side bracket with the first term in right side bracket, then second term etc..

Is this undefined because $\infty -\infty $ is undefined?

[image]

Comment: The sum you have in mind is $1-1+1-1+\cdots$ which is not convergent.

Comment: @Semiclassical  is right. Additionally, in advanced probability (not sure about elementary probability. kinda forgot), the way it goes is like $E[X]$ is defined if $E[|X|]$ is defined as a finite (real) number. Something like $|X| = X^+ + X^-$ and $X = X^+ - X^-$. In which case $E[X^+ - X^-]$ is going to be a finite real number that we define for $E[X]$. Ok not so elementary. But anyway, the moral is...

Comment: ... that I think $E[X]$ shouldn't be defined if $E[|X|]$ isn't (even if we have like what would be '$E[X]$' as finite even though $E[|X|] = \pm \infty$ or does not exist)... soooo another approach I guess is to just (try to) compute $E[|X|]$ and see that $E[|X|] = \pm \infty$ or does not exist, which I think here is a lot easier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Infinite sums are defined only as the limit of the finite sums leading up to it.  As you say, each of your parenthesized terms is infinite.  If the infinite sum is absolutely convergent, you can commute the terms however you want and the sum will remain the same.  Absolutely convergent demands that the sum converge when all the terms are made positive.  Your sum is not absolutely convergent because if we change the central minus sign to plus the sum diverges.  If the sum is not absolutely convergent the result depends on the order we sum the terms.  You chose an order, which seems to you to be the natural one, but there is nothing special about it.  That order cancels the positive terms with the negative terms one by one, giving a result of $0$.  Another order takes two terms from the first group for every term in the second.  This sum diverges to $+\infty$.  As we cannot get a unique consistent answer, we say the sum is undefined.